# I used "--amend" to change message but it is not updated on github

Tags: git, github

As mentioned in the title, I used "git commit --amend" to change the message that I wrote when I committed.

When I checked with "git log", the message is successfully changed.

However, the change is not updated on GitHub (see the highlighted part in the picture)

What should I do to change the message on GitHub? Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fH8v.png)

Comment: Push the commit up.

Comment: push gave me an error so I pulled and then pushed which solved the problem! thanks!

Comment: git push -f (However, this is really dangerous, if other people are currently working on the same branch as you do because, it will change their git history).

Answer (score 0):

The commit on GitHub will only be updated when you `push` the commit with the new message. Be aware, however, that it is a completely new commit. If anyone already pulled your old commit and is working on top of it, they will re-add your old commit with the old message when they push.

This is also the reason for you having to push with the `--force` argument, because you overwrite your old commit and therefore change your branches history.